# crontabs automatically getting deleted

Tags: linux, centos, cron

I have two users.

1. tech
2. root.

Crontabs from tech are working fine.

Crontabs for root are getting deleted and replaced by a default text. This happens within 24 hours.

I dont know why.

Comment: does it execute, what does the cronlog say?

Comment: crons do execute. But they disappear in some time.